# Robots.txt - disallow crawling one directory on subdomain

Tags: robots.txt

I have placed my product showcase on subdomain such as `http://demo.domain.com/productname/`. Demo version of product is located at `http://demo.domain.com/productname/demo/`. I would like to disallow crawling demo version, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The robots.txt must be in the root; if you have placed your Demo Version Of product in subdomain's folder then you need to change subdomains robots.txt file which should be aka; http://demo.domain.com/robots.txt

robots.txt:

```
user-agent: *
disallow: /productname/demo
allow: /
```